# netstat command shows SYN_RECV

Tags: netstat

I am using tcpsockets. All of a sudden my connection went in SYN_RECV state. Here is the output of netstat. Any clue?

```
tcp        0      0 n2cbaq112:11021       n3bvap112:57150 SYN_RECV
tcp        0      0 n2cbaq112:11021       n3bvap112:46137 SYN_RECV
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical inbound TCP connection opening is a handshake comprising 3 packets:

1. the remote sends a packet with the `SYN` flag
2. we reply with a `SYN,ACK` packet
3. the remote sends an `ACK` packet

Each step is associated with a transition and `SYN_RECV` indicates that the connection is in-between steps #2 and 3. Normally this state is transient as the handshake is almost instantaneous and the connection moves to the next state: `ESTABLISHED`.

In your case your machine is not receiving the packet with the `ACK` flag that completes the handshake. When this happens, the kernel will wait for about 30s to a minute (typically) for the `ACK` packet to be retransmitted by the remote host, and if not received in time it will eventually clean-up the state: the TCP stack will reset that state and from then on require a full handshake to take place, ignoring any late `ACK` that may arrive after this waiting period.